# upload picture over 16kb vs2010 c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, upload

I want to uplode large pictures (over 16kb) to database.(I succeeded with small pictures)
I have already changed the MaxArrayLength to 2147483647 (by default it was 16384) in all places it found.
but still I get this error message after debbuging:

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:PicToAdd. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type BL.BE.Picture. The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 41545.'.  Please see InnerException for more details 
source code:

```
Line 218:        public string BLS_AddPicture(BL.BE.Picture PicToAdd) {
Line 219:            **return base.Channel.BLS_AddPicture(PicToAdd);**
Line 220:        }
```

What Can I do to fix it as quick as possible!!!
Thanks

Comment: What does `innerException` property says? How are you uploading the file - is there web service involved any where? If yes, what kind of implementation - WCF based or asmx?

Comment: The inner exepsion was null but in the error there is quotes of it.I use Web Service

Comment: In addition- my web service is based wcf

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the setting XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength in your WCF configuration.

You can do it in the config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding ...>
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                              maxStringContentLength="8192"
                              maxArrayLength="16384"
                              maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                              maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
```

or in code:

```
XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas lOQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
           {
                    MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxDepth = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue
           };

myBinding.ReaderQuotas = lOQuotas;
```

Comment: the first possibility I have already did. it didn't help This is in my web config- <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding ----     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="163840000"/>--

Comment: Regarding to your second possibilty : where I need to add it (which file and between which tags?

Comment: You have to change this on both sides (server and client)! The second option is C# code - there are not "tags". You have to do it also on the server and client side of your wcf channel. You can put the code right where you setup your wcf channel.

Comment: server you mean the web service, yes? and client is the website?     I didn't set up my wcf channel in the web service because in vs2010 it is not required, so where i need to put it? (I have one cs file-I service that contains automatic code)

Comment: Where is your WCF client? A browser speeks the HTTP protocol and can display HTML pages.

Comment: I have class library "BlClient" that contains web service refernce. I have ASP.NET web site that contains all web pages.

Comment: I have also web service that his service is a class library project "blServer"

Comment: So i guess BlClient contains your WCF Client and blServer contains your WCF server?

Comment: Sorry, I am new with this material.   I hope you are right. (just for understanding well- in blserver i dont have web.config file, just in the web service.   in blclient i have app.config . in the web site i have web.config also)

Comment: myBinding refers to the actual binding you create. But you don't have to write code - just put it in your app/web.config on both client and server.

Comment: In all app/web config i put it already and it still doesn't work!